# all of a sudden my child theme style.css is being ignored? Its been working fine for months?

Tags: css, child-theme

anyone have any idea what could have caused this?

Thanks

https://www.subscriptionboxaustralia.com/directory/

Comment: Difficult to debug, it looks like you are using CloudFlare minifications / performance improvement features. Try to disable them and see if depends on it.

Comment: Could you include your child theme's `functions.php`? This will help us debug your issue. I have posted an answer below. MY code works also for WordPress 5, I think your child theme is enqueuing your style.css in the wrong order or not at all.

Comment: My funtions php in child theme

<?php
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { 
      wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style') );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>

Answer (score 0):

### Required (child) Theme Files

Check if your child theme has a

- style.css
- functions.php
- screenshot.png (optional, but will help you differentiate)

Recommended basic `functions.php` for a child theme

```
<?php
/**
 * Example child theme Remzi Cavdar
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/
 *
 * 
 */


function use_parent_theme_stylesheet() {
    // Use the parent theme's stylesheet
    return get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css';
}

function child_theme_branding() {

    // Uncomment this if you want versioning in your child theme stylesheet
    // $themeVersion = wp_get_theme()->get('Version');

    // Enqueue our style.css with our own version
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme-branding', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), null );

}

// Filter get_stylesheet_uri() to return the parent theme's stylesheet
add_filter( 'stylesheet_uri', 'use_parent_theme_stylesheet' );

// Enqueue this theme's scripts and styles (after parent theme)
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_branding', PHP_INT_MAX );
```